# Cocoapods reset pod configuration in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, cocoapods

Is it possible (and if it is, how?) to restore the default configuration for a single or multiple pods without reinstalling them completely? 
For example I have changes multiple build settings (e.g. linker flags) for the pod target and now I want to restore the default configuration for this pod in the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I wanted to discard all the changes I've made in source code of a Pod while testing its functionalities. I've tried:

1. `pod update POD_NAME`,
2. `pod install`,
3. removing Pod folder from the project + running `pod install`/`pod update`,

but none of these discarded my changes.

**This worked**:

1. remove Pod from a `Podfile`,
2. run `pod install`,
3. add Pod to a `Podfile`,
4. run `pod install`.

I know it's not optimal solution but it does the job.